# Can't seem to drop duplicates on one dataframe but can do it for another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For one Pandas dataframe in the same code, my drop_duplicates() seems to work and for the other it does not work. I can't seem to figure this out.

The situation where it is not working:

```
df_select
df_select= #Cont on the next line     
df_select.drop_duplicates(subset='RoundDown',keep='first',inplace=False)

df_select
```

[image]

The situation where the drop duplicates works:

```
df_select1 = pd.DataFrame( {'RoundDown': 
               [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3],'RoundUp':[0.01,np.nan,0.4,np.nan]})
df_select1

df_select1 = 
df_select1.drop_duplicates(subset='RoundDown',keep='first',inplace=False)
df_select1
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `df_select.RoundDown.unique()`?

Comment: array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.3,  0.4])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `fillna` and using `duplicated`

```
df_select1=df_select1[~df_select1.RoundUp.fillna('NaN').duplicated()]
df_select1
Out[212]: 
   RoundDown  RoundUp
0    0.10000  0.01000
1    0.20000      nan
2    0.30000  0.40000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wen-Ben for helping me !

Comment: Apologies @coldspeed . I had clicked on it and was told to wait for five minutes and then was away from my stackovwerflow account for a while. Thanks.